# Excel - VBA insert Row Error 424 "Object required

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying insert a row from VBA in an Excel sheet, everything I have read so far leads me to think the code below should work, it fails as explained below.

When I look at the opened document it has actually selected the relevant cell A7.

```
    Dim xlx As Object, xlw As Object, xls As Object, xlc As Object


    ' Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlx = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          Set xlx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    xlx.Visible = True

    Set xlw = xlx.Workbooks.Open("my.xlxs")

    Set xls = xlw.Worksheets("Offer")
    xlw.sheets("Offer").Activate
    xls.range("A7").select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

'Line breaks here with Error "Compile Error" "Variable no Defined" with ActiveCell highlighted?
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
Thanks in advance
Andrew

Comment: Try replacing your last two lines by this:
xls.range("A7").EntireRow.Insert

Comment: Try `ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like the code should be run from a different application such as Access.  Access (or whichever application) won't know what ActiveCell means.

Replace the last three lines of code with `xls.Range("A7").Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert` - there's no need to active the sheet or select a cell in the range before adding a row.

Edit - as you always select A7 and offset by one, will be easier just to use A8 instead.

Comment: Thanks Darren that sorted it for me.